Isn't the fundamental group a hom functor?
Can you not define the fundamental group as $\pi_1 := hTop_*\big((S^1,s_0),-\big)$ ?
(You would need to prove it has a group structure separately.)
I thought this was so, but then I saw that $\pi_1$ didn't preserve pullbacks, but hom-functors preserve limits.
What am I missing? It could be that the pullbacks people say are not preserved, are not actually being taken in $hTop_*$ but in $Top_*$, or something like that, and that is what breaks things. Or maybe you can't think of it as a Hom functor. I don't know.
Thanks in advance!

Incidentally, the group structure could be viewed as coming from a structure of cogroup object on $(S^1, s_0)$, where the comultiplication map $(S^1, s_0) \to (S^1, s_0) \vee (S^1, s_0)$ is $e^{i\theta} \mapsto \begin{cases} i_1(e^{2i\theta}), & 0 \le \theta \le \pi, \ i_2(e^{2i\theta}), & \pi < \theta < 2\pi \end{cases}$; the coinverse map is $e^{i\theta} \mapsto e^{-i\theta}$; and the coidentity map is the unique map to the zero object of $hTop_*$.

@DanielSchepler That's so interesting; thanks! And I assume this kind of reasoning also helps for defining $\pi_n$, right?

Presumably people are talking about pullbacks in $\mathrm{Top}*$ since the "standard" way to think of $\pi_1$ is as a functor $\pi_1\colon \mathrm{Top}* \to \mathrm{Grp}$. Pullbacks in $\mathrm{hTop}*$ are a bit fickle (one might intuitively hope that a pullback in $\mathrm{hTop}$ is the same thing as a homotopy pullback in $\mathrm{Top}_$, but this is not so; in particular $\mathrm{hTop}*$ does not have all pullbacks). That being said, your formula for $\pi_1$ is correct; you'll often find it written as $[S^1, {{-}}]*$ (with implicit basepoints).

@BenSteffan I see, that's reassuring. Thanks. I'll have to be careful. I might ask then: can I use this to prove $\pi_1$ preserves products? or does that break as well? Having that proof for free was really appealing, but now I see it's more complex than I initially thought.

@BenSteffan Also, if you want you can write this as an answer to mark the question resolved. Cheers!

@Julián You could use it since products in $\mathrm{hTop}*$ are the same as products in $\mathrm{Top}$, but it's a bit like cheating: This fact is something you should then prove, and the proof amounts to more or less the same argument as showing that $\pi_1$ preserves products in $\mathrm{Top}_$ (which is not hard to begin with) :). I'll write up an answer.

I see! You've been very helpful. Thanks. :D

Usually when people are talking about $\pi_1$ as a functor they are talking about $\newcommand{\Top}{\mathrm{Top}}\newcommand{\Grp}{\mathrm{Grp}}\pi_1\colon \Top_* \to \Grp$, not about $\newcommand{\hTop}{\mathrm{hTop}}\pi_1\colon \hTop_* \to \Grp$, so when somebody says "$\pi_1$ doesn't preserve pullbacks" what they generally mean is that it doesn't preserve pullbacks in $\Top_*$.
The reason for this is that $\hTop_*$ is not so nicely behaved as a category: it fails to be both complete and cocomplete, in particular it neither has all pullbacks nor all pushouts (one would naively hope that a pullback in $\hTop_*$ is the same thing as a homotopy pullback in $\Top_*$, but this unfortunately turns out to not necessarily be the case). Thus, we generally avoid working directly with $\hTop_*$ when we can work with $\Top_*$ instead, in particular since $\Top_*$ also encodes more information than $\hTop_*$.
As for your definition/observation, it's perfectly fine/correct. In fact, you'll often find $\pi_1 = [S^1, {{-}}]_*$ in texts dealing with homotopy theory where $[{{-}}, {{-}}]_*$ is a more commonplace way to write $\hTop_*({{-}}, {{-}})$ and basepoints are suppressed from the notation.

:D - I'll add this as a comment so I can look it up later and maybe it's useful for someone else even if it's "obvious". I assume that then $\pi_1 : Top_* \rightarrow Grp$ is defined as $(\pi_1 : hTop_* \rightarrow Grp) \circ (U : Top_* \rightarrow hTop_*)$ for $U$ the forgetful functor.

@Julián You can define it like that, sure (although I wouldn't call $U$ a "forgetful" functor; even though it inarguably "forgets" some information one thinks of it more as taking a quotient on hom-sets, or if one approaches it from a fancier perspective of e.g. model categories as taking a localization. Not aware of a standard name, however). One could also see this "definition" $\pi_1\colon \mathrm{Top}_* \to \mathrm{Grp} = (\pi_1\colon \mathrm{Top} \to \mathrm{Grp}) \circ U$ as simply stating that $\pi_1$ is homotopy-invariant if you assume the definitions given :)
